# Strange CSS 3Dmatrix transform value on chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

here's a js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gnbL88w0/1/

```
<head>
<style>     
 #test {
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transform: rotateY(90deg);
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="test"></div>
 <div id="output"></div>
<script>
 var test = document.getElementById("test");
 var output = document.getElementById("output");

 output.innerHTML = window.getComputedStyle(test).transform;
</script>
</body>
```

When I apply transform: rotateY(90deg) to a div and try to get the transform matrix through window.getComputedStyle() it returns:

matrix3d(6.12323399573677e-17, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 6.12323399573677e-17, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)

Whereas FF for example returns:

matrix3d(0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);

And IE 11 returns:

matrix3d(0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);

The questions is - why does chrome return 6.12323399573677e-17 instead of 0?

Comment: i think that about Z-axis.. (not sure)

Comment: could it be a rounding error? 6.12323399573677e-17 converted to a decimal notation is 0.0000000000000000612323399573677.